# Insite: Trying to create a custom theme, css isn't working

Tags: css, console, themes, e-commerce

I'm new to Insite, and I'm trying to create a custom theme using their demo site as a base. The default theme that the site uses is InsiteManufacturing (which inherits the Responsive theme). When I load up the site, it looks like this (I added a custom homepage to the InsiteManufacturing theme to override the one in Response).

[image]

To make a custom theme, I made an exact copy of the InsiteManufacturing directory and put in the Themes folder, and renamed it "CustomSite". Then in the Insite Console, in Website Settings > Theme I changed the Theme Value to "CustomSite". When I refreshed the site, it has the content but no styles.

[image]

Why aren't the styles being applied? The directory is exactly the same as the InsiteManufacturing directory, other than the name (and the HTML on the home page).

I know that Insite is finding the CustomSite theme, because 1) the HTML on the homepage is correct ("Hello! (Custom Theme)") and 2) when I put a non-existent theme name in the Console, I get an error loading the page. So CustomSite is being found, but the styles aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up the theme.config file in your custom theme telling it what the parent theme is.  Take a look at the theme.example.config in the Themes folder.